# Having trouble changing the title of a UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the basic master-detail list app template that Apple provides in X-Code.  The default title for the table in template program is "Master".  I've tried changing the title by going into the MasterViewController implementation and, in the viewDidLoad method, setting self.tableView.tableHeader view to a UILabel I created.  Here's the code I've tried in order to do this, but it doesn't change the title "Master" at the top, it just prints my UILabel underneath the title, making it look like the first section header in the list.

```
UILabel* title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight)];

title.text = @"A Title Here";
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = title;
```

I also tried just setting self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil; and that did not cause the "Master" title to disappear.

Comment: If you're using Interface Builder, check all your `IBOutlet` connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the tableView.tableHeader view does exactly that, sets the "first section header in the list".

If you are talking about setting the title of the view itself, the one that sits on the navigation bar, you don't need to create a label and add it to anything. All you need to do is set: self.title = @"A Title Here";

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `tableHeaderView` in this method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

For example:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel* title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight)];

    title.text = @"A Title Here";
    return title;
}
```